# Multiple chains in PyMC - apparent non-repeatability

Tags: pymc

I have seen related questions on the problems with re-seeding in PyMC (e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/95514/pymc-random-seed-doesnt-guarantee-the-same-posterior-samples), but the answers I have seen do not fully address the problem I have.

I have set up a simple Bayesian linear regression model, and have run 5 chains, each time re-seeding the numpy random number generator with the same nominal value of 123456. I expected that the traces would be identical, but this is not the case. Four of the output traces are identical, but one is different. Similar behaviour is seen if I re-run the code.

I'm running PyMC version 2.3.2.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pymc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Number of traces to run
n_trace = 5
itr = 50000
brn = 5000
thn = 5

# Generate artificial data
N = 100
intercept = 4
slope = 1.5
true_x = np.random.uniform(0, 50, N)
true_y = slope*true_x + intercept
data_y = true_y + np.random.normal(0, 5, size=len(true_y))

for i in xrange(n_trace):
    print '\nTrace {0} of {1}'.format(i+1, n_trace)

    # Re-seed random number generator
    pymc.numpy.random.seed(123456)

    # MODEL ===========================================================================
    # Define priors on "orphan" random variables
    sig_y = pymc.Uniform('sig_y', 0, 10)
    th0 = pymc.Normal('th0', mu=0, tau=0.0001)
    th1 = pymc.Normal('th1', mu=0, tau=0.0001)

    # Define deterministic linear predictor Xtrue -> Ytrue
    @pymc.deterministic
    def y_pred(x=true_x, th0=th0, th1=th1):
        return th0 + th1*x

    # Likelihood of observed y data
    y_obs = pymc.Normal('y', mu=y_pred, tau=1/sig_y**2, value=data_y, observed=True)

    M = pymc.MCMC(pymc.Model([th0, th1, sig_y, y_obs, y_pred, true_x]))
    M.sample(iter=itr, burn=brn, thin=thn, verbose=0)
    # MODEL ===========================================================================

    print '\nTrace {0}'.format(i+1)
    print('E[th0]:{0:8.3f}\tStd[th0]: {1:8.3f}'.format(M.trace(th0)[:].mean(), M.trace(th0)[:].std()))
    print('E[th1]:{0:8.3f}\tStd[th1]: {1:8.3f}'.format(M.trace(th1)[:].mean(), M.trace(th1)[:].std()))
    print('E[s_y]:{0:8.3f}\tStd[s_y]: {1:8.3f}'.format(M.trace(sig_y)[:].mean(), M.trace(sig_y)[:].std()))
```

Output (note that I've manually removed the progress bars for clarity):

```
>>> import PyMC_Ex1_LinReg as lr

Trace 1 of 5
E[th0]:   4.176 Std[th0]:    1.008
E[th1]:   1.515 Std[th1]:    0.037
E[s_y]:   5.031 Std[s_y]:    0.364

Trace 2 of 5
E[th0]:   4.191 Std[th0]:    1.044
E[th1]:   1.514 Std[th1]:    0.038
E[s_y]:   5.040 Std[s_y]:    0.368

Trace 3 of 5
E[th0]:   4.176 Std[th0]:    1.008
E[th1]:   1.515 Std[th1]:    0.037
E[s_y]:   5.031 Std[s_y]:    0.364

Trace 4 of 5
E[th0]:   4.176 Std[th0]:    1.008
E[th1]:   1.515 Std[th1]:    0.037
E[s_y]:   5.031 Std[s_y]:    0.364

Trace 5 of 5
E[th0]:   4.176 Std[th0]:    1.008
E[th1]:   1.515 Std[th1]:    0.037
E[s_y]:   5.031 Std[s_y]:    0.364
>>>
```

Comment: When I run your code, I get different values than you do, also not reproducibly.

Comment: Thanks - reassuring that I haven't done something stupid, but not reassuring about the non-repeatability issue.

Comment: If I move the random seed to the top of the script, I can reproduce the results 5 times in a row by restarting Python between runs.  So it is *possible* to get reproducible results, just not intuitive.

Comment: did you figure out what the problem was? I am having a similar problem...

Comment: Hi Laura, no, I never got to the bottom of it satisfactorily. Although Abraham D Flaxman's approach above is a bit of a workaround. I don't use PyMC much at the moment, so no urgency on my part. However, they might have fixed the issue in newer versions. If not, it might be worth digging into the source code yourself.